# Configuring mongodb on MAMP

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, mamp

So I've tried almost all the tutorials I've found here and on other sources but the problem is always the same. The extension is not installed when I call the phpinfo method.
I've added the file mongo.so to the extensions folder and I've called it on the php.ini as extension=mongo.so.

I'm using MAMP 2.2 on Mavericks and the php version is 5.5.3.

Appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of phpinfo() will tell you which php.ini file (if any) is in use.
You have to modify that php.ini file and add extension=mongo.so and then restart your webserver.

One thing you need to keep in mind when you are installing the MongoDB driver for MAMP is the `pecl` command you are using is actually the MAMP command, not some alternative PHP install you may have on your system.

To do this, locate the PHP binary distributed with MAMP, and the use the full path to the `pecl` command of the MAMP installation.

Comment: When I run the command sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pecl install mongo it just installs on computer and not on MAMP so I can't add mongo.so to MAMP using that method doesn't work

Comment: What was the path it installed to? If you could include the last ~10-15 lines of the output of the command, that would help. It should tell you exactly which folder it installed the mongo.so into - but you still need to modify the php.ini and add extension=mongo.so there (note: verify with phpinfo() that you are modifying the correct php.ini)

Comment: I've solved my problem after 3 days of research, thanks a lot for trying to help, the problem was just de version of php, apparently php 5.5.3 does not support the existing extension of mongo I'm now using php 5.4.10

Comment: Yes it does. I test every day on PHP 5.3.27 and 5.4.19 and 5.5.3.. So.. You'll have to be more explicit what exactly isn't working, error messages, what you have tried and so on..

Comment: So probably it's something with the mongo.so file, the phpinfo() doesn't show anything about mongo it looks like I haven't added nothing to php.ini, I'm sure I'm modifying the right file, I tested it, and I've no errors at least where I'm looking

Comment: Make sure you look into your error log. It could be complaining about incompatibility, in which case the "pecl" tool you used was part of another PHP installation on your system.